# Overlay video after set time offset with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, delay, offset

I'm trying to add overlays to an input video with ffmpeg that appear some time after the video starts.

The basic way to add an overlay is:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "movie=overlay.avi [ovl]; [in][ovl] overlay" out.avi
```

But this adds the overlay video (or image) from the start of the input video until one of the videos ends.

I know how to offset the overlay video using `movie=overlay.avi:seek_point=1.4`, but what about an offset on the input video?

I could always clip the video to the desired point, add overlay on the second clip, then stitch the two but that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on [arttronics' insightful, but speculative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720328/85950), **video can indeed be easily be overlaid offset using the `-itsoffset` flag.**

The [`-itsoffset`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) flag works like so:

> **-itsoffset *offset* (*input*)**
>
> Set the input time offset in seconds. [-]hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported. The offset is added to the timestamps of the input files. Specifying a positive offset means that the corresponding streams are delayed by *offset* seconds.

(NB: Despite the phrase "input file**s**", the flag actually applies only to the input immediately following it.  Note also [this bug](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1349) about offsets not applying to audio streams.  H/T [attronics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1195891/arttronics).)

So overlaying with an offset is as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.avi -itsoffset 2 -i over.avi -filter_complex overlay out.avi
```

This works regardless of the container type.

Comment: **-1** The use of `-itsoffset` will apply the offset to **BOTH** files, not just the `overlay.avi` file. Reference [**ffmpeg Ticket 1349 itsoffset doesn't work for second input file**](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1349). Furthermore, the excerpt you posted confirms it's both **files**: ***the timestamps of the input files***

Comment: @attronics No, that's wrong.  The docs are poorly written, but that bug ticket you mention is only for audio streams, and, more importantly, **this works**.  Running the given command with current builds of FFmpeg has exactly the desired effect of delaying the overlay.

Comment: Please revise your answer to include the docs are misleading, e.g. edit, so I can then Upvote. Thanks for clarifying. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

According to the limited [**FFmpeg overlay documentation**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1), the process expects that both **videos** have the same `timestamp`  (e.g., 0:00:00:00) value to keep things in sync, and ***warns*** if not done then the `avi.out` will have an ***unwanted offset*** from the `overlay.avi` video file used.

***However, you can use that that fact and take advantage of it!***

It's then conceivable that if the `overlay.avi` video has a starting `timestamp` with the ***desired offset*** which is **required** on the `in.avi` input video, then the `overlay.avi` video will fire at that same `timestamp` (*provided by `in.avi`*) to create the expected outcome for the `out.avi` video.

The only bad news is the `.avi` container *doesn't have timestamps*, unlike `.mp4` or `.mkv` file formats that do. You will have to switch to a file format that supports `*timestamps*` for this to work (e.g., `overlay.mp4` or `overlay.mkv`) for creating the final ***output video file*** required.