# A random pixel on a keyframe. (ffmpeg)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

**Hello folks of SO!**

We're trying to do some very small and simple code in PHP to generate a variation of a video, using always the same file.

The script would have to make a small pixel mark, on random or specific frame of the video file, and this would have to be streamed in real time.

**Here's some pseudo code to explain my idea:**

```
$frame = $_GET[frame];
$videofile = 'video.avi';

make_random_red_pixel_mark($videofile, $frame);
```

Does anyone know if this is possible using ffmpeg? As well, it is of extreamly importance for us, to execute this procedure as fast as possible.

A solution that would imply reprocessing the whole video, won't be useful for our purposes. It should be something like a closed caption, or a quick image / overlay filter that could be applied without an entire video reprocessing. As well, we can't put the overlay using Javascript nor any HTML approach, since the actual manipulation has to be on the video file itself.

The quality, and framerate of the original video, should be kept intact. Perhaps some other PHP module or software that could be execute from PHP using an exec()?

Any recommendation?

**Thanks in advance!!

Chris C. Russo**

**More information:**

**1)** It's possible for us to apply this procedure on any frame we want to, so we could use a "keyframe" in order to avoid the decoding and reencoding of an entire GOP.

**2)** As previously stated, the video stream would have to flow in real time.

Comment: PHP may not be the best way to do this  as it's not powerful enough. You may want to look into a binary server-side solution and call it from PHP.

Comment: Indeed my friend, by any chance do you know any software that could do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can search for FFMPEG options. You may want to search for something like "ffmpeg overlays" -- then figure out where you want the pixel, then figure out how you can specify frames, if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131020/overlay-video-after-set-time-offset-with-ffmpeg seems like a good start along with http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1

Comment: @RobW The `overlay` video filter requires re-encoding and I believe Chris Russo wants to avoid this if "reprocessing" also includes or implies re-encoding. Also your overlay URL is old: [overlay video filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1).

Comment: Thanks in any case @RobW and LordNeckbeard

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem. The FFmpeg overlay video filter requires re-encoding.

When you change **ALMOST** anything in a video, you will be dealing with re-encoding of the video. This might be an expensive process depending on the video and on the how hurry you are (if you want real-time, you are in a hurry).

A possible solution for this would be something like this:

- Open the INPUT video.
- Create the OUTPUT video.
- Loop over the packets of the INPUT video until you find the frame you want.
- Reading the flags of the video packets (AVPacket structure) you can identify the [Group of Pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) of this frame.
- Ok, you will have to RE-ENCODE only the frames that belong to this group of pictures. Because a GOP always start with a keyframe, you will be able to do that.
- After done, go on reading the packets of the INPUT and writing it to the OUTPUT (transmux).

The process of reading a packet from source and write to destination is called **transmux** and is very very cheap for live streaming. It's basically a plain copy of bytes. No big deal.

*"The hard part here is that you will have to manage a POOL of packets until you identify the GOP where your frame is located. Why? Because you will read all packets AND STORE them in a pool (without decode the packets). When you identify it's a GOP, you will write these packets to your OUTPUT and go on to the next GOP. So you will always have the GOP in memory to be flushed (all packets together). When you identify the target frame you wanna modify. I will have to DECODE THE FRAMES from the beginning of the GOP to the end, modify the frame you want and then REENCODE this GOP! Well very hard!"*

For arbitrary videos, this process above may result in a visible difference of quality of encoding in the GOP you reencoded. :-(

If you don't know how to open a video, read the packets, write the packets, etc, etc... you will have to know the basics os FFmpeg.

In order to do that, I suggest you to study this example if you don't know anything about:

1. Demuxing: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2demuxing_8c-example.html
2. Muxing: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html

This example will teach you how to open the video, identify the audio/video streams and loop over the packets, as well as decoding and reencoding.

Hard job. These examples are in C. You can decide make a plugin for PHP or use a PHP wrapper for FFmpeg.

OTHER SOLUTION IS: If you have flexibility of choose frame, try to reencode only keyframes. Because keyframes are complete "bitmaps". You don't need to deal with GOPs. You will decode and reencode only 1 frame.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response. It actually looks like a real solution for this problem! Fortunatly, we do have flexibility on the frame, so we can use a keyframe as you mentioned. In this case, if I understood you, we could only decode and reencode 1 frame, which would be the goal. Do you believe it might be possible to make this process while we're streaming the video? In other words, could we load the original video on a buffer, and create another output buffer to stream the contents, only editing (and displaying on demand) the pre-selected frame?

Comment: Yes, it is possible! If you understand those 2 files muxing.c and demuxing.c you will be able to do that. ;-)

Comment: My friend, this might be a little bit off topic, but since we have a budget for this, I'd like to speak with you on facebook. You seem to be the right person for this part of the project.